# What is the best approach to host multiple (lets say 5) sub domains on Azure Application Gateway?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-gateway

How many rules, http settings, health probes and backend pools are needed to host subdomains of the same parent domain  on the same application gateway deployment. Examples of using subdomains could be http://sub1.abc.com, http://sub2.example.com, http://app.example.com, api.example.com and so on.
We are using azure app services (web apps and API) no VMs.

TIA,

Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, some little on-topic trivia, you can use the domain example.org in documentation (and questions) knowing that it is reserved solely for this purpose, as abc.com is a real domain. More details here: https://www.iana.org/domains/reserved I've heard off some horror stories (albeit quite funny) of people using the "make believe" top level domain ".xxx" in documentation, whereas that is now a real domain of a subject matter they didn't intend to link to!

Comment: I have edited the name of the domains to example

Answer (score 2):

For each subdomain, you need a Listener and a backend pool and a HTTPSettings. The current limit is 100 Listeners, 100 Backend pool, 100 Rules, 100 HTTP Settings per Application gateway.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-subscription-service-limits#application-gateway-limits

Comment: Thanks for bringing clarity to this matter, @msrini-MSIT, can we use the same HTTP settings and health probes in case of Azure Web apps?

Comment: Nope. When Application Gateway sends probe, Azure WebApp will expect the hostname as that of the WebApp's domain name. So, you need to use custom domain and assign that to HTTP Settings. A HTTP Settings cannot use multiple probes. So you need to create 100 probes and 100 HTTP Settings and attach Health Probe to the HTTP Settings accordingly.

Comment: I think there's a scope for re-using the health probe, if the path you're checking is the default root "/" and you've checked the box for picking up the hostname form backend settings. In that case it will work.

Comment: Yeah, you are correct. You can reuse the Probe if the path is same